# pymc3 TypeError: Unsupported dtype for TensorType: object

Tags: python, statistics, pymc3

I am trying to determine the parameters mu1, mu2, sigma1, sigma2, and w of a bimodal distribution using pymc3. I use the following code:

```
# Generate sample data
import numpy as np
from pylab import concatenate, normal

# First normal distribution parameters
mu1 = 1
sigma1 = 0.1

# Second normal distribution parameters
mu2 = 2
sigma2 = 0.2

w1 = 2/3 # Proportion of samples from first distribution
w2 = 1/3 # Proportion of samples from second distribution

n = 7500 # Total number of samples

n1 = int(n*w1) # Number of samples from first distribution
n2 = int(n*w2) # Number of samples from second distribution

# Generate n1 samples from the first normal distribution and n2 samples from the second normal distribution
y = concatenate((normal(mu1, sigma1, n1), normal(mu2, sigma2, n2)))


# Recover parameters mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2 and w from the sample data
import pymc3 as pm
from scipy.stats import norm
model = pm.Model()

def logp(mu, sigma, w, y):
  mu1 = mu[0]
  mu2 = mu[1]
  sigma1 = sigma[0]
  sigma2 = sigma[1]
  return np.log(w * norm.pdf(y, mu1, sigma1) + (1-w) * norm.pdf(y, mu2, sigma2)).sum()

with model:

  # Priors for unknown model parameters
  mu = pm.Normal("mu", mu=0, sigma=1, shape=2)
  sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1, shape=2)
  w = pm.distributions.continuous.Uniform("w")

  # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
  likelihood=pm.DensityDist('Likelihood', logp, observed=dict(mu=mu, sigma=sigma, w=w, y=y))

start = pm.find_MAP(model = model)
```

The following is the error stack trace:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py in dtype_specs(self)
    279                 "complex64": (complex, "theano_complex64", "NPY_COMPLEX64"),
--> 280             }[self.dtype]
    281         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'object'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
12 frames
<ipython-input-30-12971af8f9da> in <module>()
     25 
     26   # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
---> 27   likelihood=pm.DensityDist('Likelihood', logp, observed=dict(mu=mu, sigma=sigma, w=w, y=y))
     28 
     29 start = pm.find_MAP(model = model)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymc3/distributions/distribution.py in __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs)
    120         else:
    121             dist = cls.dist(*args, **kwargs)
--> 122         return model.Var(name, dist, data, total_size, dims=dims)
    123 
    124     def __getnewargs__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymc3/model.py in Var(self, name, dist, data, total_size, dims)
   1165                     distribution=dist,
   1166                     total_size=total_size,
-> 1167                     model=self,
   1168                 )
   1169             self.observed_RVs.append(var)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymc3/model.py in __init__(self, name, data, distribution, total_size, model)
   1871             datum.missing_values for datum in self.data.values() if datum.missing_values is not None
   1872         ]
-> 1873         self.logp_elemwiset = distribution.logp(**self.data)
   1874         # The logp might need scaling in minibatches.
   1875         # This is done in `Factor`.

<ipython-input-30-12971af8f9da> in logp(mu, sigma, w, y)
     15   sigma1 = sigma[0]
     16   sigma2 = sigma[1]
---> 17   return np.log(w * norm.pdf(y, mu1, sigma1) + (1-w) * norm.pdf(y, mu2, sigma2)).sum()
     18 
     19 with basic_model:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   1738         args = tuple(map(asarray, args))
   1739         dtyp = np.find_common_type([x.dtype, np.float64], [])
-> 1740         x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)
   1741         cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)
   1742         cond1 = self._support_mask(x, *args) & (scale > 0)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/var.py in __truediv__(self, other)
    168 
    169     def __truediv__(self, other):
--> 170         return theano.tensor.basic.true_div(self, other)
    171 
    172     def __floordiv__(self, other):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/graph/op.py in __call__(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    248         """
    249         return_list = kwargs.pop("return_list", False)
--> 250         node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
    251 
    252         if config.compute_test_value != "off":

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py in make_node(self, *inputs)
    497         using DimShuffle.
    498         """
--> 499         inputs = list(map(as_tensor_variable, inputs))
    500         out_dtypes, out_broadcastables, inputs = self.get_output_info(
    501             DimShuffle, *inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py in as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim)
    205         )
    206 
--> 207     return constant(x, name=name, ndim=ndim)
    208 
    209 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py in constant(x, name, ndim, dtype)
    253         assert x_.ndim == ndim
    254 
--> 255     ttype = TensorType(dtype=x_.dtype, broadcastable=[s == 1 for s in x_.shape])
    256 
    257     try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py in __init__(self, dtype, broadcastable, name, sparse_grad)
     52         # True or False
     53         self.broadcastable = tuple(bool(b) for b in broadcastable)
---> 54         self.dtype_specs()  # error checking is done there
     55         self.name = name
     56         self.numpy_dtype = np.dtype(self.dtype)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py in dtype_specs(self)
    281         except KeyError:
    282             raise TypeError(
--> 283                 f"Unsupported dtype for {self.__class__.__name__}: {self.dtype}"
    284             )
    285 

TypeError: Unsupported dtype for TensorType: object
```

Updated the code as per accepted answer. Crash no longer happens but I do not get a convergence towards the solution:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
from pylab import concatenate, normal

# Generate sample data

# First normal distribution parameters
mu1 = 1
sigma1 = 0.1

# Second normal distribution parameters
mu2 = 2
sigma2 = 0.2

w1 = 2/3 # Proportion of samples from first distribution
w2 = 1/3 # Proportion of samples from second distribution

n = 7500 # Total number of samples

n1 = int(n*w1) # Number of samples from first distribution
n2 = int(n*w2) # Number of samples from second distribution

# Generate n1 samples from the first normal distribution and n2 samples from the second normal distribution
y = concatenate((normal(mu1, sigma1, n1), normal(mu2, sigma2, n2)))

def normpdf(y, mu, sigma):
    return (1 / sigma) * pm.math.exp(pow(y - mu, 2) / pow(sigma, 2))

def logp(mu, sigma, w, y):
    mu1 = mu[0]
    mu2 = mu[1]
    sigma1 = sigma[0]
    sigma2 = sigma[1]
    w1 = w[0]
    w2 = w[1]
    return pm.math.sum(np.log(w1 * normpdf(y, mu1, sigma1) + w2 * normpdf(y, mu2, sigma2)))

# Recover parameters mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2 and w from the sample data
model = pm.Model()

with model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", mu=np.array([0.5, 1.5]), sigma=1, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1, shape=2)
    w = pm.Dirichlet("w", a=np.array([1.1, 0.9]), shape=2)
    
    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    likelihood = pm.DensityDist(
        'Likelihood', logp, observed=dict(mu=mu, sigma=sigma, w=w, y=y))

start = pm.find_MAP(model=model)
print(start)
```

Output:

```
{'mu': array([-2.12059455,  1.95271142]),
 'sigma': array([0.01268331, 0.37437335]),
 'sigma_log__': array([-4.36746845, -0.98250172]),
 'w': array([0.70625152, 0.29374848]),
 'w_stickbreaking__': array([0.43862378])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) I stepped through and found that the error was on this line:

`return np.log(w * norm.pdf(y, mu1, sigma1) + (1-w) * norm.pdf(y, mu2, sigma2)).sum()`

because `scipy.stats.norm` doesn't know how to deal with pymc/Theano objects.  While I'm sure there's an easy way to get a normal density from pymc3 objects, it's also straightforward to define a function to calculate it ourselves:

```py
def normpdf(y, mu, sigma):
    return pm.math.sum((1 / sigma) * pm.math.exp(pow(y - mu, 2) / pow(sigma, 2)))

def logp(mu, sigma, w, y):
    mu1 = mu[0]
    mu2 = mu[1]
    sigma1 = sigma[0]
    sigma2 = sigma[1]
    return np.log(w * normpdf(y, mu1, sigma1) + (1-w) * normpdf(y, mu2, sigma2)).sum()

# Recover parameters mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2 and w from the sample data
model = pm.Model()

with model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", mu=0, sigma=1, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1, shape=2)
    #   w = pm.distributions.continuous.Uniform("w")
    w = pm.Dirichlet("p", a=np.array([1.0, 1.0]), shape=2)
    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    likelihood = pm.DensityDist(
        'Likelihood', logp, observed=dict(mu=mu, sigma=sigma, w=w, y=y))


start = pm.find_MAP(model=model)
```

This should work; I've not inspected the output but it at least compiles and runs without error.

Comment: It works but I would like to break the symmetry when creating mu to avoid having the same values of mu coming up. Also, we could move this question and its answer to the stats site or vise versa. Just move your answer to either site and I will delete the question. I will then upvote back on that site both of your answers.

Comment: OK, managed to initialize mu with different values. Also modified the code to use the two values of the Dirichlet distribution. However, I do not get a convergence towards the true distribution parameters. I am aware of an other solution that I have tried and works. Whatever I do here is to experiment with pymc3 as it has a lot of potential beyond what other libraries could provide. However, it is not working for what I would describe as a toy problem. What am doing wrong?

Comment: Code updated at the end of the question to return the sum of the logs.